# foldl with (++) is a lot slower than foldr

Tags: haskell

Why is foldl slower than foldr sometimes ?
I have a list of lists "a" like

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

and want to change it to a list by using fold

```
foldr (++) [] a
```

It works fine (time complexity is O(n)). But if I use foldl instead, it is very slow (time complexity is O(n^2)).

```
foldl (++) [] a
```

If foldl is just folding the input list from the left side,

```
(([] ++ [1]) ++ [2]) ++ [3]
```

and foldr is from the right side,

```
[1] ++ ([2] ++ ([3] ++ []))
```

the number of computations (++) is supposed to be same in both cases.  Why is foldr so slow? As per the time complexity, foldl looks as if scanning the input list twice as many times as foldr.  I used the following to computer the time

```
length $ fold (++) [] $ map (:[]) [1..N]   (fold is either foldl or foldr)
```

Comment: The *result* of `(++)` is supposed to be the same in both cases. That doesn't mean that the number of computations is the same though.

Comment: (big list) ++ (small list) is slower than (small list) ++ (big list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because of how `++` works. Note that is is defined by induction on its first argument.

```
[]     ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)
```

The number of recursive calls only depends on `length xs`.

Because of this, in `xs ++ ys` it is more convenient to have a small `xs` and a large `ys` than the other way around.

Note that folding on the right achieves this:

```
[1] ++ ([2] ++ ([3] ++ ...
```

We only have short (O(1)-length) lists on the left of `++`, making the fold cost O(n).

Instead folding on the left is bad:

```
((([] ++ [1]) ++ [2]) ++ [3]) ++ ...
```

The left arguments become larger and larger. Hence, we get O(n^2) complexity here.

This argument can be made more precise considering how the output list is demanded. One can observe that `foldr` produces its result in a "streaming" fashion, where demanding e.g. the first output list cell only forces a little part of the input -- only the first `++` needs to be performed, and only its first recursive step is actually needed! Instead demanding even only the first item from the `foldl` result will force *all* the `++` calls, making it quite expensive (even if each call only needs one recursive step, there are O(n) calls).